# Web config runtime section

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-config, assembly-binding-redirect

In my web config (web api application) there is the following section under `runtime` section

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

However, every time I update a package the bindingRedirect node get changed in

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
```

When this happen I experience two types of errors

At compile time I get

> warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed.

and when the application is running an error on version 4.0.0.0

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is getting really annoying I really dont understand how to found a persistent solution apart to remember to modify the runtime node to 4.0.0.0 version.

Any suggestion?